# need to change the back button name on navigation bar in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pop)];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
```

I placed the above code in iphone it is working.when i am trying it for ipad it is not working.what may be reason?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: initWithTitle:@"WatYouWnat"...simple yar

Comment: @iPatel i am unable to do that in ipad.but its working in iphone

Comment: self.navigationItem.title = @"your text";

Comment: Sorry to say that but the same code is working for me in iPad too :)

Comment: May be the view Controller don't contains the UINavigationController :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This changes `NavigationBar`'s `BackButton` text, to do before pushing a new view controller :

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"My text" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

And it works for both iPhone and iPad devices.

It looks like you linked your `UINavigationController` with Interface Builder, you should have a look at this :

[image]